A fatal error occurred: Failed to connect to ESP32: Invalid head of packet (0x00): Possible serial noise or corruption
I keep getting the error in the title when trying to upload a sketch. I have tried to switch to different USB ports, resetting the ESP32 camera wrover, resetting the IO extension board and the UNO and changing the baud rate from the default 921600 baud to 115200 baud as well as the lowest possible baud, holding the reset button when uploading the sketch. I do not believe I am missing any drivers either.
The wiring is all correct according to the assembly instructions of the starter kit, so I do not think it is an issue with wiring like other similar posts. I also want to note that I have flipped the IO extension board to the upload mode so it does not encounter any errors.
This is the output when the sketch fails to upload, I cannot find anything on the troubleshooting site which has fixed it either. I have tested the camera itself by connecting to the boards WiFi and then viewing the live feed on a local server so I know there is no issue with the camera itself.
Serial port /dev/cu.usbmodem00001
Connecting......................................

A fatal error occurred: Failed to connect to ESP32: Invalid head of packet (0x00): Possible serial noise or corruption.
For troubleshooting steps visit: https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esptool/en/latest/troubleshooting.html
Failed uploading: uploading error: exit status 2

Here are some images for reference:

Image of the smart car wires

Image of wiring from above

Image of ESP32 Wrover camera board

Image of UNO board disconnected


One potential issue that was mentioned to me was that the more complex the program, the longer it could take to upload so the baud rate needs to be decreased. I have tried the lowest baud rates with no solution. Here is the sketch I am trying to upload, which just simply connects to WiFi and then displays the networks information.
#define _UNIX03_SOURCE

#include <WiFi.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "WiFiInfo.h"

const char* ssid = "wifi";
const char* password = "passsword";

// int setenv(const char* password, const char* password);

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(1000);

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Serial.println("Starting connection to WiFi network ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  Serial.println("\n");
  
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi network ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    Serial.println("...\n");
    delay(100);
  }

  Serial.println("Connected to WiFi network ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  GetNetworkInfo(ssid);
}

void loop() {}

System information:

M2 chip
macOS Sonoma v14.6.1


Is this on MacOS? A very similar problem occurs there if the board is using the WCH serial chipset. The default driver is frustratingly compatible and almost works. The solution is so install the WCH driver (which is in Chinese and includes scary text about temporarily disabling security to install) and then be sure you use the /dev/cu.wchusbserialWHATEVER names. (This is necessary on my own Macs.)
Some boards require you to hold the boot key down during the entire upload. I've never found a pattern as to which ones; mostly I've replaced those boards with ones that use better software-managed handling of the GPIO 0 (board-specific) and EN pins.

I would upvote but I am missing 2 reputation to do so. Yes this is on macOS. I contacted the manufacturers and they said to connect it directly to the laptop via USB-C which I did but the board does not turn on at all.
It is also worth noting that the board does not have a boot button, only a reset one. I emailed them again about it explaning that the driver they included in the starter kit is only for x86_64 Intel CPUs and would not work for the ARM CPU that my laptop has as well as mentioning that the board is not turining on at all when connected directly to my laptop.

This is a problem with StackOverflow. Correct answers can't be upvoted to acquire points because nobody has the points to upvote. Dammit!
The WCH driver is poorly named, but it supports the CH34x and 910x drivers that are super common on ESP32 boards. https://learn.adafruit.com/how-to-install-drivers-for-wch-usb-to-serial-chips-ch9102f-ch9102/mac-driver-installation walks through the steps. It works on both M-series and x86.
If it's not obvious, I have this combination.

The power thing is described at https://www.robertlipe.com/usb-c-power-issues-with-development-boards/
It needs 5.1K pulldowns on each of CC1 and CC2 in order to receive power from a modern USB-C PD-aware host, like your (my) Mac.
You can solder in resistors (some boards have them and just need jumpers or solder bridges), hack up a cable to do the same, use an external hub, or (hold onto your hat) run a passive USB-C->USB-A->USB-C adapter chain; the C to A cable will have the needed resistors to power up the A ports, which you then upconvert back to C. Goofy, I know.

So you have power to ask questions, but not mark answers as correct or accept them? Man, SO is weird...

Haha the upvotes on this post gave me enough reputation to mark as answered + upvote. Thanks for the comments. I am going to try to fix this later, aditionally after raising a ticket about the ESP32 board just appearing to be dead when plugging directly into the mac, they said they will just send a replacement.

Hooray! Thank you. That bumped us both up a level.  Those of us hanging around in the slums of embedded have to really stick together to get out of n00b jail.
I've about tired of typing bang-on answers, linked to the gills, only have the OP ignore them and go silent.
If the board shows no lights, isn't recognized at all, but works when plugged into a "dumb" power source (not your Macbook's charger) I'll bet it's the CC1/CC2 thing. Of course, if it's just plain dead, it might be simply broken. This is a reason to buy multiples of cheap dev boards. Sometimes they give their lives.

You are most welcome. Agreed about being stuck in noob jail. I think I might just try to send a replacement with the board or just move onto another project and then try my hand at embedded development another time.

I suspect that higher volume crowds (like web dev or rust sucking-up) it's probably easier to score big numbers.
FWIW, the combination of ESP32 and Macs can be a happy place. In "involuntary retirement" I spend some of my coherent time using MacOS, but developing FOR a bucket of ESP32 and RISC-V SBCs and microcontrollers. It's not inherently a bad combo. (It's a UNIX that actually works sensibly on laptops...) Most of the tools are open source, so (re)building for MacOS is easy, though Homebrew makes it rare to need to do so.
I'm not assigning your projects, but don't give up.

I WILL admit that since the hardware is dirt cheap (ESP32 nanos are $3 and the S3's with 44 pins are under $5), the quality isn't always awesome (whaddya want for $2.41? :-) ) and sometimes damaging boards is easy that I tend to order a couple at a time. Spending 7 hours to find you blew a $3 board isn't awesome.
